# Three.js compute vertex normal faceted rendering?

Tags: javascript, three.js, normals

I have 2 meshes: from stl file and from my own format which an index based mesh.
My stl file has not a problem (I use STLoader) but for my own format, I use BufferGeometry and I specify 3 attributes (positions,colors) and my triangles index.
[image]

The image above resume my issue. After creating my BufferGeometry, I call computeVertexNormals.
The left image is my mesh created from my own data structure,and the right one isy my stl file.
Why do I get such different result?

[RESOLVED]

Use MeshPhongMaterial with flatShading: THREE.SmoothShading instead of MeshLambertMaterial.

Comment: Left one is the normal-inverted result?

Comment: The left one is my object after calling "computeVertexNormals" and the right one is my stl file.

Comment: You mean `flatShading: true`, I assume. Also, your custom geometry does not require normals at all in that case.

Comment: I set flatShading: THREE.SmoothShading and use a phongmaterial. For the image above, I used lambertMaterial. I have looked inside computeVertexNormals and I saw it sum up vertex normal. After that it normalize the sum without averaging it. Is it good to do that?

Comment: @ValimoRal I have no idea what you are doing. `flatShading` can be `true` or `false` only. `MeshLambertMaterial` does not support that property; `MeshPhongMaterial` does. If `flatShading` is true, the geometry does not require, or use, vertex normals.

Comment: alrtight, so for any MeshLambertMaterial usage, I expect to have a result like my left image? Because for this issue, I used index buffergeometry and MeshLambertMaterial. But now, I use MeshPhongMaterial with flatShading to false in order to have the same result as my right image (which is a imported stl file).

Comment: @ValimoRal Sorry, I do not really understand your questions or your objective. `computeVertexNormals()` computes smooth normals because your indexed buffer geometry is sharing vertices. Apparently, that is not what you want. Instead, use non-indexed buffer geometry (triangle "soup"), and specify flat normals in your geometry. That way, you can use `MeshLambertMaterial` and get the flat shading that you want.